# How to simultaneously run all JUnit tests for a Eclipse Java project without Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a small Java project in Eclipse. I have a class of JUnit tests for each class in the project. I'm using JUnit 4, and this is not a maven project.

Is there an easy way to tell Eclipse to run all tests in all test classes at once?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Right click on a source folder then `Run As… > JUnit Test`.

Comment: You could also create a parent unit test suite and list all of your tests/suites in it.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a keyboard shortcut for it?

Comment: this doesn't work when i have multiple packages under `test`. it only runs the ones directly in the `test` package, and not the rest

Comment: @Anton `Shift-Alt-X T` in Eclipse Mars, but you could do your own. Moreover, a configuration gets created and you can use it from the Run menu history (`Alt-R T`).

Comment: Also F11 runs debug session... either the current .java class you have open, or the last config you used.  ctrl+F11 to 'run', and ctrl+shift+F11 for a code coverage run.

Comment: @Joey I thought I had the same problem. I think Eclipse does something different if you right click on a package vs a source folder. Right click on a package and it only runs the tests directly in that package. Right click on a source folder and it runs all the tests even with a package hierarchy.

Answer (score 10):

Select the source directory containing all test classes, right-click, select "Run as..." and select JUnit test.